# Can Bangladeshi Lawyer practice in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, lawyer, barristers

If somebody has no Nationality card of UK, is he able to practice in UK court, although he has completed BPTC courses?

Answer (score 3):

Practising as a barrister in England and Wales requires more than completing academic courses, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barristers_in_England_and_Wales#Regulation) will tell you; passing yourself off as a barrister on the basis of a Canadian qualification and a few courses will probably land you in prison. It is not a requirement that you hold British nationality; foreign lawyers can and do represent clients - once they have qualified in England as well.

(As asked, your question could also cover Scotland and Northern Ireland, and indeed qualifying as a solicitor (in which case you probably will not practise in court). However, if you are not clear on all the differences, you will not be allowed to practise anyway.)

Comment: if somebody (Bangladeshi) just completed BPTC from UK,  will he allowed to practice UK court?

Comment: Unless you clarify what you are actually asking, neither I nor anybody else can add anything.

Comment: please give me a list of requirements,  those need to be a lawyer in UK for a foreigner..

Comment: @NaserUddinMiazi successful completion of the BPTC is not sufficient for *anyone* to practice in a court, regardless of nationality.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you must have a practising certificate to be able to practice reserved legal services (exercising rights of audience, probate activities, conducting litigation etc).

Anyone supplying such services without a practising certificate is committing a crime under the Legal Services Act 2007.

Note that providing legal advice is *not* a reserved legal service.

Now to answer the main question:

There are two types of lawyers in the UK, Solicitors, and Barristers.

A foreign lawyer may qualify as one or the other, but each type of lawyer has its own foreign qualification scheme. I will only speak for barristers.

A foreign lawyer may qualify as a barrister in the UK through the [Qualified Foreign Lawyers Scheme](https://www.barstandardsboard.org.uk/qualifying-as-a-barrister/bar-training-requirements/transferring-lawyers/qualified-foreign-lawyers/)

In the relevant [guidance](https://www.barstandardsboard.org.uk/media/1823342/transferring_qualified_lawyers_guidelines_2019.doc), for a person who is not a european lawyer, the requirements are:

> 4.5   A Qualified Foreign Lawyer may apply to the BSB for exemption from the Academic, Vocational and/or Professional Components of training. 
>   If the Qualified Foreign Lawyer has for a period of at least three
>   years regularly exercised rights of audience in courts which
>   administer law substantially similar to the common law of England and
>   Wales, the BSB will grant exemption from the Academic and Vocational
>   Components, and, if it thinks fit, from part, or all, of the
>   Professional Component of training. Exemptions will usually be granted
>   conditional on passing some or all sections of the Bar Transfer Test.
>   For the purpose of 4.5 above, courts in the following jurisdictions
>   are deemed to administer law substantially similar to the common law
>   of England and Wales:
>
> Anguilla               Antigua & Barbuda           Australia                    Bahamas
>   Bangladesh                     Barbados                    Belize                      Bermuda                     Botswana
>                      British Virgin Islands              Canada                  Cayman Islands                  Dominica                     Ghana                      Grenada                     Guyana                      Hong Kong
>   India
>   Isle of Man                Israel                          Jamaica         Malawi  Malaysia  Montserrat
>   Namibia  New Zealand  Nigeria  Northern Ireland Pakistan  Papua New
>   Guinea  Scotland Singapore  South Africa  Sri Lanka  St Kitts & Nevis 
>   St Lucia  St Vincent & the Grenadines Sri Lanka  Trinidad & Tobago
>   Turks & Caicos
>   United States of America  Zambia  Zimbabwe
>
> Other Qualified Foreign Lawyers may be granted exemptions from the
>   Academic, Vocational and/or Professional Components of training. Any
>   exemptions granted would normally be subject to passing some, or all,
>   of the Bar Transfer Test.

So it appears that a Bangladeshi lawyer can practice in the UK if they follow the necessary application procedure and prove to the UK Bar that they are an appropriately qualified foreign lawyer.

NOTE: It doesn't matter if you've completed the BPTC. That would only make you an unregistered barrister, and part of the BPTC Ethics course is knowing that unregistered barristers are not allowed to provide reserved legal services.